# spring cloud stream binder kafka doesn't work

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Now I'm trying to create Message Service function with kafka to use `spring-cloud-stream-bind-kafka`, but didn't work so well.

`Configuration:`
spring boot 1.4.2

`build.gradle:`

```
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:2.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:2.0.1.RELEASE"
```

`code:`

```
@EnableBindings(MessagePublish.class)
class MessageConfiguration {
}

interface MessagePublish {
    @Output("test")
    MessageChannel publish();
}

class TestService {
    @Autowired
    MessagePublish messagePublish;

    public void doSomething() {
        // do something
        messagePublish.publish().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());
    }
}
```

It failed when I start the project with this error log

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.cloud.stream.config.BindingServiceConfiguration.bindingService
....
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.integration.support.converter.ConfigurableCompositeMessageConverter
```

I'm suspecting my spring boot version. It's so low version.
I think `spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka` can't be used under spring boot 2.0 version or other reasons.

I don't know how can I do and how can I explore this situation...
If you give me a little advice, I really appreciate you.

Comment: I strongly suggest spring boot 2, there has been too many changes. I suggest you to generate the pom starting from https://start.spring.io/ for the correct dependencies and versions

Comment: I also want to use spring boot 2, but I can't(maybe..). Cause this project is really huge legacy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot `1.4.x` version then you should use the Spring Cloud Camden release train.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-cloud/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Camden-Release-Notes

In particular, you should use the following versions:

```
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream:1.1.2.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka:1.1.2.RELEASE"
```

Comment: Those versions are extremely old and no longer supported. Even Boot 1.5 goes out of support soon.